# Broken CSS - box with corner images

Tags: html, css

EDIT:

Used code from Tim and it worked!!!
The only question I have is how to make my header to be independent of the rest of the body and strech across the screen as in template image without any padding from the top and sides?

Here is the design template:
[design template](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6734/templatel.gif)

Here is an updated code html + css:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Rounded Corner Tutorial</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            body{padding: 10px; background-color: #e8e8e8; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
            h1{padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}

            #container{

                    margin:0px auto;
                    border:0px solid #bbb;
                    padding:0px;
                    }
            .white-box{width: 180px; margin: 0px;}


            #main-header {
                border:1px solid #bbb;
                height:80px;
                padding:10px;
                background:#FFF
            }

            #main-content {
                margin-top:10px;
                padding-bottom:10px;
            }

            #main-body {
                margin-left:10px;
                width:666px;
                height:150px;
            }

            #main-footer {

                margin-top:10px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
            padding:10px;
            border:1px solid #bbb;

            }   


            .box {
                padding: 8px;
                border: 1px solid silver;
                -moz-border-radius: 8px;
                -o-border-radius: 8px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 8px;
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            .box1 {
                width: 200px;
                float: left;
            }

            .box2 {
                margin-left: 224px; 
            }


            </style>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div id="container">

            <div id="main-header">Main Header</div>
                <div id="main-content">

                    <div class="box box1">
                    left
                    </div>

                    <div class="box box2">
                    <p>Main Bbody 1...</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="main-footer">Main Footer</div>
            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: If I'm getting what you're trying to achieve, you want to make rectangles with rounded corners. If that's the case, no need to use sprites for this. Try the CSS3 `border-radius` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border-radius` and ditch the images. It will make your life much easier and will look sharp on displays with high pixel density (unlike a GIF).

- Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QXqzd/1/
- Browser Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius
- More examples: http://muddledramblings.com/table-of-css3-border-radius-compliance/

**Important Part**

```
.box {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; /* older versions of FF */
    border-radius: 8px; /* IE9+, Webkit, etc. */
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**All CSS**

I created a rough CSS stylesheet to match your template.

```
body { 
    background-color: #eee; 
}

.box {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.box1 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.box2 {
    margin-left: 224px;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box box1">
    left
</div>

<div class="box box2">
    right
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your sample worked perfectly! The only thing is header not streaching... (please see my updated post)

Comment: One way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/QXqzd/2/. I removed margin and padding from the `body` and put the header outside of the container.

Comment: Tim, I hate to bother you again... I like how the right box streches out when browser winow gets expanded. Is there any way to stop the resizing of the right box (say at 900px) the other way, when browser window gets downsized to the left?

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with Tim.
I'm not sure if it's necessary now with CSS3, but in the past, to ensure cross-browser compatibility, you needed additional code for Mozilla and Safari/iPhone browsers in addition to border-radius:

```
.box {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Either way, it doesn't hurt to add those two extra lines in, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: i think if you are on an old browser you need those. i am on an old firefox broswer right now. Tim's fiddle doesnt work

Comment: Hard to say how many people are still using older versions of FF, so I updated my example. Webkit-based browsers have worked for quite some. Note that the standard property `border-radius` should be included after any vendor-specific prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion code, may can solve your problem:

```
.your_css_rounded_column {
   border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yYjrB/